Interface or type where type of one field depends on type of another one
I already have similar question: Declare type where type of one field based on value of another field
The main difference is that now I don't know the list of possible values
So let's say that I have these interfaces:
interface One {
    children: Child[]
}

interface Child<T = any> {
    props: T,
    component: (props: T) => null
}

const ComponentOne = (props: string) => null;
const ComponentTwo = (props: number) => null;

const one: One = {
    children: [
        {
            props: 5,
            component: ComponentOne
        },
        {
            props: 'string',
            component: ComponentTwo
        }
    ]
}

I need to props have exact same type as props of component.
The code above doesn't give any errors because of any but if I remove it the interface One will break because it will require the type for Child but it can't be same for all of them
This may be a very obvious question, but I can't figure out how to fix it
P.S. I wrote interface without any reason if it is possible to fix using type then it is acceptable for me

TS doesn't have existentially quantified generics, which is what you're looking for. You either need to do this with mapped array types as shown in this playground link or you have to emulate existentially quantified generics which involves some indirection as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz To be honest I don't know the answers to your questions because I don't understand the prons and cons of each method which you provided. IMHO the first one is easier to read but I don't understand how does Child<T[I]> works because for me you are passing Child into Child and it works with some magic and in this case the error occurs on component not on props. I understand that it doesn't matter because the solution will be the same it just a little confusing, like TS wants to props of component be like props not the vice versa...

Also it is easier for me to change it in project beacuse I should do it in a lot of places, because in this method I should wrap only parent element not the every child. The second method is much more harder to read and understand (I mean that if I return to this types after 2 months I believe that I will not understand what is going on here :) ). Also it requires to wrap every child but it shows error on props like I wanted. If it is not possible to solve this problem without wrappers then you can write an answer and please explain the prons and cons of each method if they are exists

The linked q/a above explain the different methods.  Pros and cons depend on your use cases. Both involve helper functions since TS cannot infer generic type arguments for generic types, only when you call generic functions. If you can't understand existential types or the other one gives you an error, you might decide to use them just to validate input, and then use any inside your implementations. There's not much more I can say here that hasn't been said in the other answers linked above. Good luck!

If you don't want to use a generic function you should take some efforts to build the type yourself. For example you could use:
interface One<T> {
    children: (T extends any ? Child<T> : never)[]
}

to distribute props type to different child objects, so it would become not Child<string|number>[] but (Child<string>|Child<number>)[] (you can remove Simplify utility and inline ONE, it was done for debugging and demonstration):
Playground
type Simplify<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? T[K] extends (...args: infer B) => infer A ? (...args: B) => Simplify<A> : never : Simplify<T[K]>} extends infer A ? A : never;

const ComponentOne = (props: string) => null;
const ComponentTwo = (props: number) => null;
const Components = [ComponentOne, ComponentTwo];

{

interface One<T> {
    children: (T extends any ? Child<T> : never)[]
}

interface Child<T> {
    props: T,
    component: (props: T) => null
}

type ONE = Simplify<One<Parameters<typeof Components[number]>[0]>>;

const one: ONE = {
    children: [
        {
            props: '',
            component: ComponentOne
        },
        {
            props: 1,
            component: ComponentTwo
        }
    ]
}
}
// ==================== alternative ===================
{

interface Child<C extends (props: any) => null> {
    props: Parameters<C>[0],
    component: C
}

interface One<C extends (props: any) => null> {
    children: (C extends any ? Child<C> : never)[]
}


type ONE = Simplify<One<typeof Components[number]>>;

const one: ONE = {
    children: [
        {
            props: '',
            component: ComponentOne
        },
        {
            props: 1,
            component: ComponentTwo
        }
    ]
}
}


Thanks! This is not what I'm looking for, but it's a very interesting approach that I hadn't thought of. +1
